# Wordpress ajax returning html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Am using WordPress ajax to load the sub-categories dynamically.

Here's my code

Php code

```
  function techento_getsubcat() {
  $category_name = $_POST['catname'];
  $cat_id = $_POST['catid'];
  return wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Choose a Sub              Category&tab_index=10&taxonomy=category&hide_empty=0&child_of=' . $cat_id . '' );

  }
  add_action('wp_ajax_techento_getsubcat', 'techento_getsubcat');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_techento_getsubcat', 'techento_getsubcat');
```

Jquery

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $('#cat').change(function(e){
   alert("changed");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: pcAjax.ajaxurl ,
        data: { 
            'action': 'techento_getsubcat', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
          'catname':    $('#cat option:selected').text(), 
            'catid':    $('#cat option:selected').val() },
        success : function(response){
                 alert(response);
             console.log(response);

           $("#subcats").html(response);

        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();

      });
  });
```

The problem with the above code is that php returns the raw html irrespective of the  thing asked to return

even if set it to

```
    return true;
```

it then returns the raw html of subcategories generated plus '0'

Comment: setting `dataType` is only to tell `$.ajax` what to expect as return, it won't change what is returned from server. really not clear what your issue is

Comment: I had set    "return true;" but inspite it returns html generate from wp_dropdown_category @charlietfl

Comment: `return true` on what? your explanation is not very detailed

Comment: this is what response i get  "http://i.imgur.com/Ks9vs7B.png"     only expected response is "0" as for testing purposes it made it to return true

Comment: can you organize your code a bit? also, the php function `techento_getsubcat` should have a `die();` at the end, and don't return the `wp_dropdown...` as it's already echoed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the **`$`** shortcode in

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

The Ajax callback is better handled by [`wp_send_json_success()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_success), so we don't have to worry with `return` or `echo`, `exit` or `die`. For that, set `echo` to false in the [dropdown arguments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories):

```
function techento_getsubcat() {
    $cat_id = intval( $_POST['catid'] );
    $args = array(
        'hide_empty'         => 0, 
        'echo'               => 0,
        'child_of'           => $cat_id,
        'taxonomy'           => 'category'
    );
    $data = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
    wp_send_json_success( $data );
}
```

On Ajax success, use `response.data`:

```
success : function(response){
    console.log(response.data);
}
```

Comment: so not having the $ sign is what causes this issue?

Comment: yeah, check [WordPress and jQuery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91598/12615) and [Why $ for jquery doesn't work?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/55230/12615)